# Arduino MEGA - Why is my timer interrupt incorrect on first run?

Tags: c++, c, timer, arduino

I am writing a stepper driver class for an Arduino MEGA 2560 using the Arduino Timers, but I'm running into some unexpected behavior out of the timer used. The essence of what I'm going for is the following:

- Stepper Speed Ramp Class: contains speed ramp information like max speed, acceleration, deceleration, an array for OCR values, etc.
- CL42T Class: this class inherits (publicly) the Stepper Speed Ramp class, and contains timer register pointers, I/O port register pointers, timer masks, and a few other member variables.

To test this class structure, I've written a sketch to test run the stepper motor for one revolution (of the subassembly), increase the speed, and repeat. Unfortunately, I am experiencing very odd behavior out of the timer during the first loop of my sketch (as well as the fourth loop) where The timer seems to be at a much higher frequency than expected, thus running the motor at some awful speed and not the currently set "maxSpeed". Loops 2 and 3, as well as up to 10 have shown the expected behavior, but I have not gone beyond 10 to look for any deeper patterns.

I know that the init() function adjusts the timer registers before setup, so I clear the control registers for timers 1 through 5 in setup(). I want to potentially use micros() and/or millis() for this application, so I'm steering clear of messing with Timer 0.

After all of my troubleshooting, I've stayed consistent with two potential root causes (although I can't seem to locate the smoking gun for either):

- Through the class structure, I'm setting timer control registers in an incorrect order or something of the sort.
- Some sort of overflow or other calculation / data type error. I've looked through this, and looked up all of the C++ standard promotions, but I can't seem to find anywhere that would cause a problem in the CalculateSpeedRamp() member function. Furthermore, I've printed out the OCR array values and confirmed them against manual calculations - no issues found.

I'm using VS Code v1.62.0, with Arduino extension v0.4.7, and C/C++ extension v1.7.1.

Here is my code below, along with the serial monitor output from running my test. Can anyone locate where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance for the assistance!

CL42TClassTest.ino:

```
#include "CL42T.h"

// prescale value
int PreScale = 8;

// Step Counter
volatile unsigned long TestStepperSteps = 0;
bool oneShot = true;

const char TestStepperStepPort = 'E';
const int TestStepperStepBit = 3;
const int TestStepperControlBit = 2;
const int TestStepperTimerNum = 3;
const char TestStepperTimerOutput = 'A';
const int TestStepperOneRevSteps = 27774;

// create test stepper object (global object)
CL42T TestStepperDriveObject(TestStepperStepPort,TestStepperStepBit,TestStepperControlBit,TestStepperTimerNum,TestStepperTimerOutput,PreScale);

// Macros for anscillary equipment
#define VDC24_Setup DDRF |= B00010000   // set 24VDC Control Relay pin to OUTPUT
#define VDC24_On    PORTF |= B00010000  // set 24VDC Control Relay pin HIGH
#define VDC24_Off   PORTF &= B11101111  // set 24VDC Control Relay pin LOW

// max speed variable
int MAXspeed = 60; 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200); // start serial at 115200 BAUD
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial to connect
    }
    // header
    Serial.println(F("Program to test CL42T Class."));
    // clear timer registers and print verification
    clearTimersOneToFive();
    Serial.println(F("Timers 1-5 Register Values After Reset:"));
    // proceed to print out all timer 1-5 control registers, TCNT values, and OCR values...

    // setup 24VDC relay and ensure OFF
    Serial.print(F("Setting up 24VDC control relay..."));
    VDC24_Setup;
    VDC24_Off;
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    // setup stepper drive object
    Serial.print(F("Setting up Test Stepper drive object..."));
    TestStepperDriveObject.SetupDrive();
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    // Timer settings printout
    Serial.println(F("Setup Timer Settings: "));
    Serial.print(F("OCR3A Value: "));Serial.println(OCR3A);
    Serial.print(F("TCNT3 Value: "));Serial.println(TCNT3);;
    Serial.print(F("TCCR3A Value: "));prntByteBIN(TCCR3A);
    Serial.print(F("TCCR3B Value: "));prntByteBIN(TCCR3B);
    Serial.print(F("TCCR3C Value: "));prntByteBIN(TCCR3C);
    Serial.print(F("TIMSK3 Value: "));prntByteBIN(TIMSK3);
    Serial.print(F("TIFR3 Value: "));prntByteBIN(TIFR3);
    // Step pin port values printout
    Serial.println(F("Setup DDRE and PORTE: "));
    Serial.print(F("DDRE = "));prntByteBIN(DDRE);
    Serial.print(F("PORTE = "));prntByteBIN(PINE);
    // indication for main loop start
    Serial.println(F("Now starting main loop..."));
    delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
    if (oneShot)
    {
        // Timer settings printout
        Serial.println(F("First Loop Timer Settings:"));
        // procede to print out all timer 1-5 control registers, TCNT, and OCR

        // Step pin port values printout
        Serial.println(F("First Loop DDRE and PORTE:"));
        Serial.print(F("DDRE = "));prntByteBIN(DDRE);
        Serial.print(F("PORTE = "));prntByteBIN(PINE);
        // CL42T class settings
        Serial.println(F("C42T Class Settings: "));
        // proceed to print out all CL42T object values (addresses, masks, etc.)

        // StepperSpeedRamp class settings
        Serial.println(F("StepperSpeedRamp Class Settings:"));
        // proceed to print out all StepperSpeedRamp object values
    }
    // set maxSpeed of drive & calculate OCR array, then apply
    TestStepperDriveObject.SetMaxSpeed(MAXspeed);
    TestStepperDriveObject.ApplyNewSpeed();
    // turn on 24 VDC
    Serial.print(F("Turning on 24VDC Control Relay..."));
    VDC24_On;
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    delay(1000);
    // enable drive
    Serial.print(F("Enabling Test Stepper Drive..."));
    TestStepperDriveObject.EnableDrive();
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    // set drive direction
    Serial.print(F("Setting Test Stepper Direction to FWD..."));
    TestStepperDriveObject.SetDirection('F');
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    // move stepper drive one revolution
    Serial.print(F("Starting Test Stepper at "));Serial.print(MAXspeed);Serial.println(F(" mm/s for one revolution..."));
    TestStepperDriveObject.Increment(TestStepperOneRevSteps);
    // monitor for end of movement
    while (TestStepperSteps < TestStepperDriveObject.incrementSteps)
    {
        Serial.print(F("Steps taken: "));Serial.println(TestStepperSteps);
        delay(250);
    }
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    // clear step tracker
    TestStepperSteps = 0;
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    // disable stepper drive
    Serial.print(F("Disabling Test Stepper Drive..."));
    TestStepperDriveObject.DisableDrive();
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    delayMicroseconds(500);
    // turn off 24VDC
    Serial.print(F("Turning off 24VDC Control Relay..."));
    VDC24_Off;
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    // adjust max speed up 20 mm/s
    MAXspeed += 20;
    // delay to slow test progression
    delay(3000);
}

void prntByteBIN(byte b)
{
    for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Serial.print(bitRead(b,i));
    }
    Serial.println();
}

void clearTimersOneToFive()
{
    noInterrupts();
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 0;
    TCCR1C = 0;
    TIMSK1 = 0;
    TCNT1H = 0;
    TCNT1L = 0;
    TIFR1 |= B00001111;
    TCCR2A = 0;
    TCCR2B = 0;
    TIMSK2 = 0;
    TCNT2 = 0;
    TIFR2 |= B00001111;
    TCCR3A = 0;
    TCCR3B = 0;
    TCCR3C = 0;
    TIMSK3 = 0;
    TCNT3H = 0;
    TCNT3L = 0;
    TIFR3 |= B00001111;
    TCCR4A = 0;
    TCCR4B = 0;
    TCCR4C = 0;
    TIMSK4 = 0;
    TCNT4H = 0;
    TCNT4L = 0;
    TIFR4 |= B00001111;
    TCCR5A = 0;
    TCCR5B = 0;
    TCCR5C = 0;
    TIMSK5 = 0;
    TCNT5H = 0;
    TCNT5L = 0;
    TIFR5 |= B00001111;
    interrupts();
}

// Test Stepper Step Interrupt
ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect) {
    if (((*TestStepperDriveObject.stepPIN) & (1<<TestStepperDriveObject.stepBIT))) {
        TestStepperSteps++;        
        if ((TestStepperDriveObject.incrementSteps > 0) && (TestStepperSteps >= TestStepperDriveObject.incrementSteps))
        {
            TestStepperDriveObject.StopDrive(); // position reached, stop drive
            // TestStepperSteps = 0;
        }
        if (TestStepperSteps <= TestStepperDriveObject.accelSteps)
        { // acceleration phase
            if (!(TestStepperSteps % TestStepperDriveObject.speedUpdateSteps))
            {
                TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex++;
                *TestStepperDriveObject.stepOCRH = highByte(TestStepperDriveObject.OCRarray[TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex]);
                *TestStepperDriveObject.stepOCRL = lowByte(TestStepperDriveObject.OCRarray[TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex]);
            }
        }
        if ((TestStepperDriveObject.incrementSteps > 0) && (TestStepperSteps >= (TestStepperDriveObject.incrementSteps - TestStepperDriveObject.decelSteps)))
        { // deceleration phase - position tracking only
            if (!(TestStepperSteps % TestStepperDriveObject.speedUpdateSteps))
            {
                *TestStepperDriveObject.stepOCRH = highByte(TestStepperDriveObject.OCRarray[TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex]);
                *TestStepperDriveObject.stepOCRL = lowByte(TestStepperDriveObject.OCRarray[TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex]);
                TestStepperDriveObject.accelDecelIndex--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CL42T.h:

```
#ifndef CL42T_h
#define CL42T_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "StepperSpeedRamp.h"

class CL42T: public StepperSpeedRamp
{
public:
    // register pointers
    volatile uint8_t *directionPORT;
    volatile uint8_t *directionDDR;
    volatile uint8_t *directionPIN;
    volatile uint8_t *enablePORT;
    volatile uint8_t *enableDDR;
    volatile uint8_t *enablePIN;
    volatile uint8_t *alarmPORT;
    volatile uint8_t *alarmDDR;
    volatile uint8_t *alarmPIN;
    volatile uint8_t *stepPORT;
    volatile uint8_t *stepDDR;
    volatile uint8_t *stepPIN;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRA;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRB;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRC;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTIMSK;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTIFR;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCNTH;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCNTL;
    volatile uint8_t *stepOCRH;
    volatile uint8_t *stepOCRL;
    volatile uint8_t *stepOCRH2;
    volatile uint8_t *stepOCRL2;
    // timer register masks
    uint8_t stepTCCRAmask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRAOutput1Mask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRAOutput2Mask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRBmask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRBstartMask;
    uint8_t stepTimerOutputInterrupt1Mask;
    // dual or single motor toggle variable
    volatile int numMOTORS;
    // step and control bits
    volatile int stepBIT;
    volatile int stepBIT2;
    volatile int controlBIT;
    volatile int controlBIT2;
    // step target value
    volatile int incrementSteps;
    // single motor constructor:
    CL42T(char StepPort, int StepBit, int ControlBit, int TimerNum, char TimerOutput, int PreScale);
    // dual motor constructor:
    CL42T(char StepPort1, int StepBit1, int ControlBit1, int TimerNum1, char TimerOutput1, int StepBit2, int ControlBit2, char TimerOutput2, int PreScale);
    void SetupDrive(); // setup pointers, port directions, etc.
    void ApplyNewSpeed(); // set OCRL/OCRH to OCRarray[0]
    void SetDirection(char DriveDir); // set direction of CL42T stepper driver
    void EnableDrive(); // enable CL42T stepper driver
    void DisableDrive(); // disable CL42T stepper driver
    void RunDrive(); // run single mmotor or both motors
    void StopDrive(); // stop single motor or both motors
    void Increment(int IncrementSteps); // run at maxSpeed for IncrementSteps
};
#endif
```

CL42T.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "CL42T.h"

/*
* Single Motor Constructor:
* - set numMOTORS to 1
* - copy relevant parameters
* - set step pointers
* - set timer pointers and timer masks
*/
CL42T::CL42T(char StepPort, int StepBit, int ControlBit, int TimerNum, char TimerOutput, int PreScale)
        :StepperSpeedRamp(PreScale)
{
    // this is the single motor constructor - sets timer register pointers and timer register masks.
    
}

/*
* Dual Motor Constructor:
* - set numMOTORS to 2
* - copy relevant parameters
* - set step pointers
* - set timer pointers and timer masks
*/
CL42T::CL42T(char StepPort, int StepBit1, int ControlBit1, int TimerNum, char TimerOutput1, int StepBit2, int ControlBit2, char TimerOutput2, int PreScale)
        :StepperSpeedRamp(PreScale)
{
    // this is the dual motor constructor - sets timer register pointers and timer register masks.
   
}

/*
* Setup:
* - Set control I/O registers
* - Clear timer registers
* - Setup timer, but don't start it
*/ 
void CL42T::SetupDrive()
{
    // clear timer registers and any pending interrupt flags, set timer control registers, clear TCNT, and set initial OCR value. This function DOES NOT set the clock select bits, as this is not the desired point for the timer to run.
  
}

void CL42T::ApplyNewSpeed()
{ // set OCR value from OCRarray[0]
    
}

void CL42T::SetDirection(char DriveDir)
{
    // set direction pin LOW or HIGH
}

void CL42T::EnableDrive()
{
    // set enable pin HIGH
}

void CL42T::DisableDrive()
{
    // set enable pin LOW
}

void CL42T::RunDrive()
{   
    // TCNT to zero, clear pending timer compare match interrupt flags, set clock select bits to start timer
}

void CL42T::StopDrive()
{
    // clear clock select bits in TCCRB to stop timer, disable timer interrupt, clear TCNT
}

void CL42T::Increment(int IncrementSteps)
{
    // set target steps, then call RunDrive()
}
```

StepperSpeedRamp.h:

```
#ifndef StepperSpeedRamp_h
#define StepperSpeedRamp_h

#include "Arduino.h"

// Stepper Speed Ramp Class for CL42T drives
class StepperSpeedRamp
{
public:
    // drive settings
    double maxSpeed; // mm/s
    // variables for speed ramp calculations
    double Accel; // mm/s/s
    double Decel; // mm/s/s
    double mmPerStep; // mm/step
    int preScale; // prescale selection
    long CntFreq; // counter frequency
    int speedUpdateSteps; // # steps
    long maxSpeedSteps; // # steps
    long maxAccelSteps; // # steps
    long accelSteps; // # steps
    long decelSteps; // # steps
    long numStepsTemp; // # steps
    long OCRmin;
    long OCRo;
    // speed update index (OCRarray[])
    volatile int accelDecelIndex;
    // speed ramp OCR values
    volatile uint16_t OCRarray[21];
    // member functions
    StepperSpeedRamp(int PreScale);
    void SetMaxSpeed(int MmPerSec);
    void CalculateSpeedRamp();
};
#endif
```

StepperSpeedRamp.cpp:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "StepperSpeedRamp.h"

/*
* Stepper Speed Ramp Class
*/
StepperSpeedRamp::StepperSpeedRamp(int PreScale)
{
    // drive settings
    maxSpeed = 60; // mm/s - default @ 60
    // variables for speed ramp calculations
    Accel = maxSpeed*10; // mm/s/s - accelerate in 100 ms
    Decel = maxSpeed*10; // mm/s/s - decelerate in 100 ms
    mmPerStep = 0.04; // mm/step
    preScale = PreScale; // copy prescale value into object
    CntFreq = 16000000/preScale; // calculate counter frequency at PreScale
    speedUpdateSteps = 0; // # steps
    maxSpeedSteps = 0; // # steps
    maxAccelSteps = 0; // # steps
    accelSteps = 0; // # steps
    decelSteps = 0; // # steps
    numStepsTemp = 10000; // use 10,000 steps as the calculation for speed ramp
    OCRmin = 0; // minimum delay --> max speed
    OCRo = 0; // first delay --> start speed (based on acceleration)
    accelDecelIndex = 0; // speed update index (OCRarray[])
    CalculateSpeedRamp(); // calculate OCRarray
}

void StepperSpeedRamp::SetMaxSpeed(int MmPerSec)
{
    maxSpeed = MmPerSec; // set new maxSpeed value
    Accel = maxSpeed*10; // accelerate in 100 ms
    Decel = maxSpeed*10; // decelerate in 100 ms
    CalculateSpeedRamp(); // calculate new OCRarray
}

void StepperSpeedRamp::CalculateSpeedRamp()
{
    OCRmin = ((mmPerStep*(CntFreq/2))/(maxSpeed)); // calculate minimum OCR - based on max speed
    OCRo = ((CntFreq/2)*sqrt((2*mmPerStep)/Accel)); // calculate first OCR value - based on accel
    OCRarray[0] = OCRo; // load first OCR value into OCRarray
    maxSpeedSteps = ((maxSpeed*maxSpeed)/(2*mmPerStep*Accel)); // calculate steps required to reach max speed
    maxAccelSteps = ((numStepsTemp*Decel)/(Accel+Decel)); // calculate steps required to reach max deceleration phase
    if (maxSpeedSteps < maxAccelSteps)
    { // trapezoidal speed profile
        accelSteps = maxSpeedSteps; 
        decelSteps = (accelSteps*(Accel/Decel));
    }
    else if (maxSpeedSteps >= maxAccelSteps)
    { // triangular speed profile
        accelSteps = maxAccelSteps;
        decelSteps = (accelSteps*(Accel/Decel));
    }
    speedUpdateSteps = accelSteps / ((sizeof(OCRarray)/2)-2); // 0 indexed AND OCR[0] is already filled.
    for (int i = 1;i < (sizeof(OCRarray)/2);i++)
    { // populate OCR array
        OCRarray[i] = (OCRo*(sqrt((i*speedUpdateSteps)+1)-sqrt((i*speedUpdateSteps))));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that part of this program is irrelevant to the problem and you can delete it? I suggest that you make a copy of your entire program, then delete parts of the program that you don't think are important, until the problem stops happening, then undo whatever made it stop happening, and continue. Simplify the program as much as possible, without fixing the problem. Whatever is left is called a minimal test case. During this process, you might find the answer, and if not, you can post what's left to SO without people having to read through the entire program.

Comment: @user253751, that's a fair point. There is much I can strip out which is simply copied and pasted throughout the switch cases of the CL42T class constructor to generate an MRE.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest, I think you've provided too much irrelevant code that makes it difficult to analyse what you've put together. The Atmel mnemonics (e.g. TCCR1A) doesn't make it easier. What I can recommend is to hook up a set of LEDs to the output ports (the ones you intend to connect to the stepper motor), slow down the timer so that the ISR fires in terms of once per a few seconds and verify that you get the right signaling pattern. Frome there, increase the frequency and move forward.

Comment: that is fair. I will strip out the flexible nature of the class structure I've created, and test manipulating a single timer from within a class structure. I was hoping that confirming the register values after setting them would isolate any issues from the "extra code" in the class. Also, good idea on the LEDs. I've been using an O-scope to check the output, but LED's and really slowing down the count might be enough to shed some light on the problem. Thank you for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've stripped down the code, as well as combined them into a single file     in order to streamline testing the architecture concept (code embedded at the end).

I think I have found the smoking gun - my OCR register is being set too low, likely as the last assignment of the acceleration phase. I caught it by printing the current OCR value at the same time I print the current step count. Here is a snippet of the serial output which shows the smoking gun:

```
Setting max speed...Done.
maxSpeed = 60
Accel = 600
Decel = 600
maxSpeedSteps = 75
maxAccelSteps = 5000
accelSteps = 75
decelSteps = 75
OCRo = 11547
OCRmin = 666
OCR 1 = 3094
OCR 2 = 2266
OCR 3 = 1873
OCR 4 = 1633
OCR 5 = 1466
OCR 6 = 1342
OCR 7 = 1245
OCR 8 = 1166
OCR 9 = 1101
OCR 10 = 1045
OCR 11 = 997
OCR 12 = 955
OCR 13 = 918
OCR 14 = 885
OCR 15 = 855
OCR 16 = 829
OCR 17 = 804
OCR 18 = 782
OCR 19 = 761
OCR 20 = 742
Starting movement...
OCR3A = 11547
Steps taken: 60
OCR3A = 742
Steps taken: 298
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
Steps taken: 1002
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
Steps taken: 1707
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
Steps taken: 2412
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
Steps taken: 3117
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
Steps taken: 3822
OCR3A = 144 <---------- OCR somehow too low
... // and it continues on until deceleration, which behaves as it should.
```

My hypothesis is that I am assigning a value to the OCR register which is outside the bounds of my OCR array. However, I am not sure how it is happening. The steps are only updated during the acceleration phase and deceleration phase, and the speed update "distance" (steps before adjusting OCR) is calculated from the number of acceleration steps, so I don't see how I can get a mismatch between the array index and the array bounds. Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include "math.h"

class SpeedRamp
{
public:
// private:
    long maxSpeed; // mm/s
    long Accel; // mm/s/s
    long Decel; // mm/s/s
    double mmPerStep;
    int preScale;
    long CntFreq;
    long maxSpeedSteps;
    long maxAccelSteps;
    long numStepsTemp;
    uint16_t OCRmin;
    uint16_t OCRo;
// public:
    long accelSteps;
    long decelSteps;
    int speedUpdateSteps;
    volatile int accelDecelIndex;
    volatile uint16_t OCRarray[21];
    SpeedRamp();
    void SetMaxSpeed(int MmPerSec);
    void CalculateSpeedRamp();
};

SpeedRamp::SpeedRamp()
{
    maxSpeed = 60; // default to 60 mm/s
    Accel = maxSpeed*10; // accelerate in 100 ms
    Decel = maxSpeed*10; // decelerate in 100 ms
    mmPerStep = 0.04;
    preScale = 8; 
    CntFreq = 16000000L/preScale; // calculate timer count frequency based on prescale
    numStepsTemp = 10000; // use 10,000 steps as speed ramp calculation
    CalculateSpeedRamp();
}

void SpeedRamp::SetMaxSpeed(int MmPerSec)
{
    maxSpeed = MmPerSec;
    Accel = maxSpeed*10; // accelerate in 100 ms
    Decel = maxSpeed*10; // decelerate in 100 ms
    CalculateSpeedRamp();
}

void SpeedRamp::CalculateSpeedRamp()
{
    OCRmin = ((mmPerStep*(CntFreq/2))/(maxSpeed));
    OCRo = ((CntFreq/2)*sqrt((2*mmPerStep)/Accel));
    OCRarray[0] = OCRo;
    maxSpeedSteps = ((maxSpeed*maxSpeed)/(2*mmPerStep*Accel));
    maxAccelSteps = ((numStepsTemp*Decel)/(Accel+Decel));
    if (maxSpeedSteps < maxAccelSteps)
    {
        accelSteps = maxSpeedSteps;
        decelSteps = (accelSteps*(Accel/Decel));
    }
    else
    {
        accelSteps = maxAccelSteps;
        decelSteps = (accelSteps*(Accel/Decel));
    }
    speedUpdateSteps = round(accelSteps/(sizeof(OCRarray)/2));
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(OCRarray)/2); i++)
    {
        OCRarray[i] = (OCRo*(sqrt((i*speedUpdateSteps)+1) - sqrt((i*speedUpdateSteps))));
    }
}

class StepperDrive: public SpeedRamp
{
public:
    volatile uint8_t *stepPORT;
    int stepBit;
    volatile uint8_t *stepDDR;
    volatile uint8_t *stepPIN;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRA;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRB;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTCCRC;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTIMSK;
    volatile uint8_t *stepTIFR;
    volatile uint16_t *stepOCRA;
    volatile uint16_t *stepTCNT;
    uint8_t stepTCCRAmask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRAOutputMask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRBmask;
    uint8_t stepTCCRBStartMask;
    uint8_t stepTimerOutputInterruptMask;
    long incrementSteps;
    long stepsTaken;
    StepperDrive();
    void SetupDrive();
    void SetMaxSpeed(double MmPerSec);
    void RunDrive();
    void StopDrive();
    void Increment(long IncrementSteps);
};

StepperDrive::StepperDrive()
            :SpeedRamp()
{
    stepPORT = &PORTE;
    stepBit = 3; // PE3
    stepDDR = &DDRE;
    stepPIN = &PINE;
    stepTCCRA = &TCCR3A;
    stepTCCRB = &TCCR3B;
    stepTCCRC = &TCCR3C;
    stepTIMSK = &TIMSK3;
    stepTIFR = &TIFR3;
    stepOCRA = &OCR3A;
    stepTCNT = &TCNT3;
    stepTCCRAmask = B00000000;
    stepTCCRAOutputMask = B01000000; // COM3A0 = 1 (toggle on compare match)
    stepTCCRBmask = B00001000; // WGM32 = 1 (CTC, mode 4)
    stepTCCRBStartMask = B00000010; // CS31 = 1 (prescale 8)
    stepTimerOutputInterruptMask = B00000010; // OCIE3A = 1 (enable interrupt A)
    stepsTaken = 0;
    incrementSteps = 0;
}

void StepperDrive::SetupDrive()
{
    // clear timer registers
    *stepTCCRA = 0;
    *stepTCCRB = 0;
    *stepTCCRC = 0;
    *stepTIMSK = 0;
    *stepTCNT = 0;
}

void StepperDrive::SetMaxSpeed(double MmPerSec)
{
    SpeedRamp::SetMaxSpeed(MmPerSec); // adjust private maxSpeed variable
}

void StepperDrive::RunDrive()
{
    if (incrementSteps == 0)
    {
        incrementSteps = -1; // if no position target, give indication to ISR
    }
    accelDecelIndex = 0; // reset accelDecelIndex (OCRarray[])
    stepsTaken = 0; // reset stepsTaken
    *stepTCNT = 0; // reset timer count
    noInterrupts();
    *stepOCRA = OCRarray[0]; // set first OCR value
    interrupts();
    *stepDDR |= (1<<stepBit); // set step pin as OUTPUT
    *stepPORT &= ~(1<<stepBit); // set step pin LOW
    *stepTCCRA = (stepTCCRAOutputMask); // enable COM3A toggle on compare match
    *stepTIMSK = (stepTimerOutputInterruptMask); // enable compare match interrupt
    *stepTIFR |= B00001111; // clear any pending interrupts
    *stepTCCRB = (stepTCCRBmask | stepTCCRBStartMask); // place timer in CTC mode, start timer at prescale 8
}

void StepperDrive::StopDrive()
{
    *stepTCCRB = 0; // stop timer
    *stepTCCRA = 0; 
    *stepTIMSK = 0; // clear interrupt enable
    *stepPORT &= ~(1<<stepBit); // pull step pin LOW
}

void StepperDrive::Increment(long IncrementSteps)
{
    incrementSteps = IncrementSteps; // set position target
    RunDrive();
}

// global stepper drive object
StepperDrive stepperTest;

// global MAXspeed variable
double MAXspeed = 60;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial)
    {
        ; // wait for serial to connect
    }
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(F("Setting up stepper object..."));
    stepperTest.SetupDrive();
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    Serial.println(F("Now starting main loop."));
}

void loop() {
    Serial.print(F("Setting max speed..."));
    stepperTest.SetMaxSpeed(MAXspeed);
    Serial.println(F("Done."));
    Serial.print(F("maxSpeed = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.maxSpeed);
    Serial.print(F("Accel = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.Accel);
    Serial.print(F("Decel = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.Decel);
    Serial.print(F("maxSpeedSteps = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.maxSpeedSteps);
    Serial.print(F("maxAccelSteps = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.maxAccelSteps);
    Serial.print(F("accelSteps = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.accelSteps);
    Serial.print(F("decelSteps = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.decelSteps);
    Serial.print(F("OCRo = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.OCRo);
    Serial.print(F("OCRmin = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.OCRmin);
    Serial.println(F("OCR array:"));
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(stepperTest.OCRarray)/2); i++)
    {
        Serial.print(F("OCR "));Serial.print(i);Serial.print(F(" = "));Serial.println(stepperTest.OCRarray[i]);
    }
    Serial.println(F("Starting movement..."));
    stepperTest.Increment(27774);
    Serial.print(F("OCR3A = "));Serial.println(OCR3A);
    while (stepperTest.stepsTaken < stepperTest.incrementSteps)
    {
        delay(100);
        Serial.print(F("Steps taken: "));Serial.println(stepperTest.stepsTaken);
        Serial.print(F("OCR3A = "));Serial.println(OCR3A);
    }
    Serial.println(F("Move complete."));
    stepperTest.stepsTaken = 0;
    MAXspeed += 10;
    delay(3000);
}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect)
{ // OC3A is on pin PE3, controlled by OCR3A
    if (PINE & (1<<3))
    { // step pin is HIGH
        stepperTest.stepsTaken++;
        if ((stepperTest.incrementSteps > 0) && (stepperTest.stepsTaken >= stepperTest.incrementSteps))
        { // if step target exists and has been reached, stop drive - targeted moves only
            stepperTest.StopDrive();
        }
        if (!(stepperTest.stepsTaken % stepperTest.speedUpdateSteps)&&(stepperTest.stepsTaken <= stepperTest.accelSteps))
        { // acceleration phase - all moves
            stepperTest.accelDecelIndex++;
            if (stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex] <= stepperTest.OCRmin)
            {
                OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRmin;
            }
            else
            {
                OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex];
            }
            // OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex];
        }
        if ((stepperTest.incrementSteps > 0)&&(!(stepperTest.stepsTaken % stepperTest.speedUpdateSteps))&&(stepperTest.stepsTaken >= (stepperTest.incrementSteps - stepperTest.decelSteps)))
        { // deceleration phase - targeted moves only
            if (stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex] <= stepperTest.OCRmin)
            {
                OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRmin;
            }
            else
            {
                OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex];
            }
            // OCR3A = stepperTest.OCRarray[stepperTest.accelDecelIndex];
            stepperTest.accelDecelIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```